# What is visual cryptography?

Tags: cryptography, visualization

**Question:**
1. What is visual cryptography?
2. How does it work for secret image sharing?

*Attempt:* I have tried to understand the concept of secret image sharing for black and white pixel from here http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/november32013/. But I have doubt about pixel expansion in this case. Suppose I have a image $212\times 212$ pixels. How can I encode this image to use as cipher text using pixel.
I want to clear my doubt. Please help me to understand this?

Comment: Basically, you make sure that the combined 4-pixel gives all black if the source pixel is black, and gives half black if the source pixel is white.

Comment: @KL, thank you for your kind response. Due to my network problem I am late.  I shall update my post with example.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is already given [here](http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/november32013/h.png):

[image: rule]

Let $\begin{matrix}\blacksquare\square\\\square\blacksquare\end{matrix}$ be **pattern 1** and $\begin{matrix}\square\blacksquare\\\blacksquare\square\end{matrix}$ be **pattern 2**.

Notice that they add up to a black square, and when added to themselves, they create a half-black square.

If the source pixel is black:

- For half of the time, give pattern 1 to the first encrypted image and pattern 2 to the second encrypted image.
- For the other half of the time, give pattern 2 to the first image and pattern 1 to the second.

If the source pixel is white:

- For half of the time, give pattern 1 to the first encrypted image and the second encrypted image.
- For the other half of the time, give pattern 2 instead.

---

#### Variations

As stated in the website, they do not have to be a checkerboard pattern.

As long as pattern 1 is the complement of pattern 2, i.e. they share no common black pixel and they add up to a large black pixel, then you can use them. You are also encouraged to use different varieties.

---

#### Program:

In [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth):

```
J.z          "assign the inputs to J" \
=GmmO6lhJlJ  "assign G to an array filled with random" \
             "numbers from 0 to 5, each corresponding" \
             "to a pattern" \
=H.e.e?q@@JkY"■"-5ZZbG \
             "assign H to G, then flip the number if" \
             "the corresponding pixel is black"
jbms`MdG\
jbms`MdH     "print both arrays"
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J.z++++++++++%22assign+the+inputs+to+J%22+%5C%0A%3DGmmO6lhJlJ++%22assign+G+to+an+array+filled+with+random%22+%5C%0A+++++++++++++%22numbers+from+0+to+5%2C+each+corresponding%22+%5C%0A+++++++++++++%22to+a+pattern%22+%5C%0A%3DH.e.e%3Fq%40%40JkY%22%E2%96%A0%22-5ZZbG+%5C%0A+++++++++++++%22assign+H+to+G%2C+then+flip+the+number+if%22+%5C%0A+++++++++++++%22the+corresponding+pixel+is+black%22%0Ajbms%60MdG%5C%0Ajbms%60MdH+++++%22print+both+arrays%22&input=%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%0A%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%0A%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%0A%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A0%E2%96%A1%0A%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1%E2%96%A1&debug=0)

Correspondence:

- `0` corresponds to $\begin{matrix}\blacksquare\blacksquare\\\square\square\end{matrix}$.
- `1` corresponds to $\begin{matrix}\blacksquare\square\\\blacksquare\square\end{matrix}$.
- `2` corresponds to $\begin{matrix}\blacksquare\square\\\square\blacksquare\end{matrix}$.
- `3` corresponds to $\begin{matrix}\square\blacksquare\\\blacksquare\square\end{matrix}$.
- `4` corresponds to $\begin{matrix}\blacksquare\square\\\blacksquare\square\end{matrix}$.
- `5` corresponds to $\begin{matrix}\square\square\\\blacksquare\blacksquare\end{matrix}$.

They are deliberately assigned so that if their code add up to `5`, then the pixels add up to a large black pixel.

Comment: @ KL, it will better if you do this. +1 for you.

Comment: @Warrior Please tell me if you need another input format. I am aware that the current input format is not so useful.

Comment: if every pixel is divided into say 2 subpixels horizontally, then this would increse the width of the superimposed image by a factor of 2??